# Is there a standardarized way in .NET to expose a push-based subscription web service?

Tags: .net, web-services, push-notification

The scenario is simple.  I have need of a service that provides subscribed clients with event notifications appropriate to their subscription data.  This is intentionally designed to reduce load on the service by preventing clients from using frequent polling.  Clearly notices will occasionally be missed so low frequency polling is a must (every 5-10 minutes), so that needs to be supported to, and to keep operating costs low, the service should be fast and light weight.  I'm very new to this territory so I'm not familiar with what is "out there" so to speak.  I'd prefer a purely .net based implementation, but node.js isn't out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like SignalR with Persistant Connections or even NetHttpBinding on WCF could take care of this.  Should have researched more.